# How to scale a rectangle by a percentage?

Tags: geometry

I'm doing something in a computer program and I feel like this has an easy math answer but it is eluding me for one reason or another. I have an image that is rather large and I am making a copy of it and scaling it down by 50% then performing calculations upon it that yields a rectangle that corresponds to an area inside of the smaller image. I would then like to scale this rectangle up so that it's correctly resized for the image that is 50% bigger.

I actually have this working by calculating the percentage difference in size and converting that to pixels and then adding this value times 2 to the height and width, however the scaling factor is fixed at 2 which correlates to the 50% reduction.

So I *think* my question is how do I calculate that scaling factor, but I may have the terminology wrong and thus what I am wanting is a formula/explanation for increasing the rectangle by the proper amount so that it matches the bigger image. As for where the rectangle is, in terms of position in the xy coordinates doesn't matter here as I am finding it by calculating the percentages for both images.

What I'd like is a generic way of expressing this but I am missing something easy in the math. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a point $(0.3w,0.2h)$ in the smaller image it will be $(0.3W,0.2H)$ in the larger image. The relative position (percentage of width/height) does not change.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank you-- I didn't realise that and my problems with scaling the rectangle incorrectly (50% versus 200%) meant I had to recalculate the positioning, however when I fixed that problem I found what you said to be true. Thank you.

Comment: A completely different question boiling down to the same problem of scaling up vs. down by percentage: [Calculating discount not working](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170647/calculating-discount-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop percentages and replace them with ordinary fractions.

Suppose you have an image 1000 units wide. If you scale it down to 50% of its original size, you scale it by factor $\frac 12$, and get an image 500 units wide.

If you want to scale it up to the original size, that is from 500 units back to 1000, you need to scale it by $2 = 1/\tfrac 12$
This is actually making the image 200% of the decreased size or, equivalently,  increasing by 100% – but certainly *not* '50% bigger'!

Comment: I think that was my hang-up-- 2 = 1/(1/2). Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan If the answer resolves your problem, please accept it so that others know the question has been answered. For more hints please see our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help), section [Asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking), topic [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and possibly [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Sorry; I didn't see the check mark there and did an upvote instead. Fixed-- and yes this solved my problem, I didn't understand that I was actually trying to scale by 200% instead of 50%. When I implemented this in code it worked perfectly. Thanks! (and accepted as an answer)